# Many To Many Plugin Template Help

Tags: plugins, relations

I am using the Many to Many plugin and wondering if the below is possible.

I have a channel called Model ID. Model ID is then related to two other sections, Memory and SSD. I want to be able to link entries from Memory to entries in SSD via the Many To Many Field within Model ID.

Below is a picture, edited, to show the field layout and the information I have within the Model ID entry. The information within the entry is what I need to pull in to my Memory and SSD section but can not figure it out.

I feel like I am missing something very simple that might not be in the read me document for the plugin.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks John

[image]

Comment: Your issue can't be solved by this code? https://github.com/page-8/craft-manytomany/blob/master/README.md#template-usage you can use this field like every other relation field in Craft.

Comment: The code there works just fine but links me to the Model ID, not to Memory or SSD section. I really feel like its an easy solution that I am not just understanding or seeing via templating.

Comment: Uhm.. So you didn't try to just grab the field value and query for the related elements `{% set ssd = entry.fieldHandle.all() %}` replace fieldHandle with the handle of the specific field. It will return an array of elements. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I am trying this but no luck - {% set modelIDs = entry.memoryModelIds %}

{% for modelID in modelIDs.all() %}
    {% set ssd = modelID.relationshipsSsd.all() %}
    {% for product in ssd%}
        {{ product.title }} - {{ product.url }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

Comment: I am currently in the Memory section trying to access information from the Model ID section. Here is the code I use to pull in the Model ID title: {% set modelIDs = entry.memoryModelIds %}

                                    {% for modelID in modelIDs.all() %}
                                        <li>{{ modelID.title }}</li>
                                    {% endfor %}

Comment: I guess that's what the plugin enables you to do - otherwise the last code would be considered as wrong unless you insert the same field in your Memory section. The first code seems a little bit confusing

Comment: Thanks Robin for the help! I think the plugin works as advertised in the Read Me file. I think I am pushing the extent of the field in my case.  Thanks again for the help and have a great afternoon!

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understand you correctly, you're trying to use the Model IDs channel as a middle man? If so, I think you would just need two steps:

**To get all SSDs from a Memory Entry**

```
{% set modelIDs = craft.entries.section('MODEL ID SECTION HANDLE').relatedTo(entry).ids() %}
{% set ssds     = craft.entries.section('SSDS SECTION HANDLE').relatedTo(modelIDs).all() %}
```

**To get all Memory from an SSD Entry**

```
{% set modelIDs = craft.entries.section('MODEL ID SECTION HANDLE').relatedTo(entry).ids() %}
{% set memory   = craft.entries.section('MEMORY SECTION HANDLE').relatedTo(modelIDs).all() %}
```